# ssl .key file lost, could i recreate it ?

Tags: linux, ssl, apache-2.4

i lost my .key file for one of my domain who was made by my ssl provider, i still got my .crt and .pem files.

Is it possible to recreate by my self a .key file matching with the certificate ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only the private key that you originally created will ever match the certificate. If it were *possible* to recreate it, then it would not be secure!

If you lose the private key, then the only thing you can do is to have your existing certificate revoked, and a new certificate issued with a new private key.

Comment: too bad for me !